# JavaScript HTML - Refine items on page by contents

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making an online shop selling laptops as a University project. All the items are stored on MySQL and transferred to the page via PHP and all contained in div tags.

I am trying to make a function using JavaScript to refine the laptops shown on the page by certain traits - CPU type (Intel/AMD), RAM size (4/8/16/32) and storage type (HDD/SSD).

I plan to turn the divs not containing the chosen refine data to hidden. A problem that already arises is the 'centeringDiv' that contains two divs to align them together on the page (I could replace this if needs be).

I've done some research but a lot of people suggest jQuery, however, **I can't use it for the project.**

Any ideas on the JavaScript I can use to search a div for certain info then make it hidden if it doesn't contain it? I will also make an order by function but not focuses on that for now. All suggestions welcome, thanks.

### Item HTML

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if ($startDiv == true) { ?>
            <div class="centeringDiv">
            <div class="laptops"><br />
                <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $row["img"] ?>"><br />
                <div class="laptopText">
                    <h3><?php echo $row["brand"] . $row["model"] ?></h3><br />
                    <p><?php echo $row["cpu_type"] . ", " . $row["cpu_model"] . ", " . $row["OS"] . ", " . $row["RAM"] . $row["RAM_type"] . ", " . $row["storage"] . ", " . $row["display"] . ", " . $row["gpu"]?></p><br />
                    <p class="price"><?php echo "£" . $row["price"] ?></p><br />
                    <div class="itemFormDiv">
                        <form method="post" action="homepage.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>">
                            <input class="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" min="1" max="9" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["brand"] . $row["model"] ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_desc" value="<?php echo $row["cpu_type"] . ", " . $row["cpu_model"] . ", " . $row["OS"] . ", " . $row["RAM"] . ", " . $row["RAM_type"] . ", " . $row["storage"] . ", " . $row["display"] . ", " . $row["gpu"]?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"] ?>">
                            <input class="addTooBasket" name="addTooBasket" type="submit" value="Add to Basket">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $startDiv = false;
        }
        else { ?>
                <div class="laptops"><br />
                    <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $row["img"] ?>"><br />
                    <div class="laptopText">
                        <h3><?php echo $row["brand"] . $row["model"] ?></h3><br />
                        <p><?php echo $row["cpu_type"] . ", " . $row["cpu_model"] . ", " . $row["OS"] . ", " . $row["RAM"]  . $row["RAM_type"] . ", " . $row["storage"] . ", " . $row["display"] . ", " . $row["gpu"]?></p><br />
                        <p class="price"><?php echo "£" . $row["price"] ?></p><br />
                        <div class="itemFormDiv">
                            <form method="post" action="homepage.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>">
                                <input class="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" min="1" max="9" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["brand"] . $row["model"] ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_desc" value="<?php echo $row["cpu_type"] . ", " . $row["cpu_model"] . ", " . $row["OS"] . ", " . $row["RAM"] . ", " . $row["RAM_type"] . ", " . $row["storage"] . ", " . $row["display"] . ", " . $row["gpu"]?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"] ?>">
                                <input class="addTooBasket" name="addTooBasket" type="submit" value="Add to Basket">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $startDiv = true;
        }
    }
```

---

### Refine HTML

```
<div class="refineExpanded" hidden="">
        <form method="post" onsubmit="refineClick()">
            <div class="refineTitle">Refine</div>
            <div class="refineCPU">
                CPU <br />
                Intel<input type="checkbox" name="CPU" id="0" value="Intel"><br />
                AMD<input type="checkbox" name="CPU" id="1" value="AMD"><br />
            </div>
            <div class="refineRAM">
                RAM <br />
                4GB<input type="checkbox" name="RAM" id="2" value="4"><br />
                8GB<input type="checkbox" name="RAM" id="3" value="8"><br />
                16GB<input type="checkbox" name="RAM" id="4" value="16"><br />
                32GB<input type="checkbox" name="RAM" id="5" value="32"><br />
            </div>
            <div class="refineStorage">
                Storage<br />
                HDD<input type="checkbox" name="Storage" id="6" value="HDD"><br />
                SSD<input type="checkbox" name="Storage" id="7" value="SSD"><br />
            </div>
            <div class="refineOrderBy">
                Order By:<select name="orderBy">
                    Order By:
                    <option value="priceH2L">Price High->Low</option>
                    <option value="priceL2H">Price High<-Low</option>
                    <option value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="refineGo">
                <input type="submit" value="Go">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: "The <center> cannot hold it is too late." PLEASE don't mix HTML and PHP code. Just don't. It's terribly confusing. Use one file for HTML and others to HTML. Read this: http://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html/

Comment: I will take a look, thanks. I am a beginner in all of this so its a learning curve and this is how I was taught.
EDIT: Just checked out the article. I am currently nesting PHP in my HTML and not echo'ing out all the HTML. How would I go about using separate files?.. This article isn't particularly helpful. @NelsonTeixeira

Comment: Well, PHP is a templating language after all... In this case, I don't think it is bad to mix it the way you did. Might be just me. Am I correct in thinking that the PHP is not that imiportant for your question anyway? It seems to me that the JavaScript part is really what your question is about. You could maybe provide some HTML that is generated by the PHP as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains a lot of code, yet the actual question is a bit unclear. Lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I am going to assume some things and show you how I would solve that. Then I hope that I actually answer your question. Feel free to ask for clarifications in the comments.

**Assumptions.** You have a bunch of items as (complex) HTML markup. Every item has the same structure, but potentially many HTML elements are involved per item. There is a separate form that users can use to filter the items by various properties.

**Approach.** Using vanilla JavaScript, we will track when users change the filter inputs and update which items should be shown. This is done by changing their [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and doing the actual hiding in CSS. Advantages of this approach are that functionality and layout are separated, and that it is easier to add nice transitions (woohoo!).

**A demo.** This is loosely based on your question. It does not do error checking, which you probably want to add. It also uses ES6, which hopefully is not a problem for you. I hope you can see how filtering can be done in vanilla JavaScript. Again, I'll be glad to clarify any uncertainties.

*Clarifications and links.* The demo uses the following functions, amongst others.
[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) results from query selectors into arrays, that are easier to index and iterate. Arrays also have many convenience methods, such as the following.
[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to easily extract values from an object via [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
[`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to easily check if an item should be hidden according to some filter.
[`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`Document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`Document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to, well, select elements. Each has their own strength.
[`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add options to the selects that are used for filtering.

```js
function addOption(select, value) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.textContent = value;
  select.appendChild(opt);
}

var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item')),
    filters = ['brand', 'price'],
    shouldShow = {};
filters.forEach(function(f) {
  // find values in all items
  var itemProperties = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.' + f)),
      allValues = itemProperties.map((el) => el.textContent),
      uniqueValues = [...new Set(allValues)],
      filter = document.getElementById(f + '-filter');
  // make sure we can store per item if it should be shown according to this filter
  shouldShow[f] = Array(itemProperties.length).fill(true);
  // create an option for no filtering and for every value
  addOption(filter, 'Show all');
  uniqueValues.forEach((v) => addOption(filter, v));
  // respond to changes in filtering
  filter.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    var sel = event.target.value;
    allValues.forEach((val, ind) => {
      shouldShow[f][ind] = (sel === 'Show all' || val === sel);
      // actually hide item if any filter wants to hide it
      items[ind].classList.toggle('hidden', filters.map((f) => shouldShow[f][ind]).some((show) => !show));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #bada55;
}
.item.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.price:before { content: "Price: "; }
.price:after { content: "."; }

.storage:before { content: "Storage: "; }
.storage:after { content: "."; }

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

#filters {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="filters">
  <label for="brand-filter">Filter by brand</label>
  <select id="brand-filter"></select><br>
  <label for="price-filter">Filter by price</label>
  <select id="price-filter"></select>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="branding">
    The brand new <span class="model">Foo Ultra 4201</span> laptop, by <span class="brand">FooBar</span>.
  </div>
  <div class="price">low</div>
  <div class="storage">HDD</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="branding">
    The great <span class="model">Foo Blurp 4202</span> laptop, by <span class="brand">FooBar</span>.
  </div>
  <div class="price">high</div>
  <div class="storage">SSD</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="branding">
    The amazing <span class="model">Calculator 2000</span> laptop, by <span class="brand">TotallyLegit</span>.
  </div>
  <div class="price">high</div>
  <div class="storage">HDD</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="branding">
    The budget <span class="model">Stick-o-tron</span> laptop, by <span class="brand">TotallyLegit</span>.
  </div>
  <div class="price">low</div>
  <div class="storage">HDD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will need to take some time to look over the JS to understand it. Once I understand more of it I will get back to you. Also, your assumption that all items are in a single container is wrong. Every two items are paired together so they can be held together horizontally on the page - I feel like this could be a problem when trying to hide only 1 of the 2 items in a pairing container. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I do not actually need that assumption. My JavaScript will consider all `.item` elements on the page. If you want to show items in two columns, you can do so using a [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) layout. You should probably ask a separate question for that.